# How to find a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

How to find a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I think that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$, but not really sure how to prove it. But even if so, how to find the right element?
Thanks.

Comment: The proof of the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) may yield the primitive element $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$, depending on how it's proved.

Comment: In any case it would be a linear combination of $\sqrt 2,\ \sqrt 3,\ \sqrt 5$.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks. I suspected that this would be the primitive element, however in order to prove it, do I have to solve 8*8 linear problem?

Comment: @Roy no, you would have to prove its minimal polynomial has degree $8$, which is equivalent to having $8$ different conjugates... (hence Andrea's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tower of extensions
$$
\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)
$$
is proper at every step, so since each step is a quadratic extension the total degree is 8. A $\Bbb Q$-basis is $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt6,\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15},\sqrt{30}\}$.
The 8 $\Bbb Q$-automorphism are those determined by any choice of signs in
$$
\sqrt m\mapsto\pm\sqrt m\qquad m\in\{2,3,5\}.
$$
The proof of the theorem of the primitive element says that an element whose conjugates are all different is primitive. Can you find one?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really familiar with the term "conjugates" in this context. Do you have a relevant link?

Comment: @Roy You've never seen the word "conjugate" in Galois theory? That's very strange. The conjugate of an element in a Galois extension $L/K$ is an image of the element under an element of the Galois group $G_{L/K}$. So for example the conjugate of $a+b\sqrt{d}$ in $F(\sqrt{d})/F$ is $a-b\sqrt{d}$, including $\overline{a+bi}=a-bi$ when $F=\Bbb R$ and $d=-1$.

Comment: @anon: No I haven't. Think I've got it though: The minimal polynomial must be the product of all $(x-c_i)$ where $c_i$ is either $\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5$ or one of its conjugates. Therefore the minimal polynomial is of degree 8.